# Do you ever see the person you escaped Helgen with again?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There's so much continuity in this game (for example meeting Cicero on the road before you see him at the Dark Brotherhood) that I thought perhaps you might get to meet the character you left Helgen with again (Hadvar or the other guy). Has anyone bumped into them? They don't seem to be in Riverwood still.

Comment: You might recognize ulfric stormcloak again in your adventures.

Comment: He's not the dude you escape with though, or is he?

Comment: Ralof? He stays in Gerdur's home. He suggests to go to Windhelm and join the Stormcloacks. Does he move later in the quest line?

Comment: The guy I escaped with was Hadvar and he's not there anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Depending on who you escaped with, you will see them again either by joining the Stormcloadk Rebellion, or by joining the Imperial Legion. However, even if you didn't follow the other guy, he will still be in the game. [SPOILER]:

> When you follow Ralof in the game, he will be at Gerdur's in Riverwood. However if you joined the Legion and started the Jagged Crown, Hadvar will be at Korvanjund where you find the Crown and Ralof will be removed when you do the Legion quests. Everything else is the opposite when you follow Hadvar and join the Stormcloak Rebellion and go to Korvanjund.

Comment: Can you spoiler me and tell me where to find them?

Comment: Hadvar lives in the first house on the left as you enter Riverwood.  He might not always be there though.  He will be present in the battle at Whiterun if you reach that point in the civil war plot.  If he dies there, you won't see him again.

Comment: Whoever you escaped with will also be with the group sent to recover the Jagged Crown (the first quest after officially joining a faction)

Comment: @Thrillho Will they be an enemy if you joined the opposite side?

Comment: @Fambida ...Actually that's a good question. I don't think I've tried joining the side of the character I didn't escape with.

Comment: I think that the person who you left behind is killed during the dragon attack because I don't believe you see them again.

Comment: @m.n.wiser the one you killed isn't left behind. It's kind of a spoiler to say this, but If you followed Ralof, and you joined the legion, in the Jagged Crown, Hadvar will be at the Ruin Korvanjund.

Comment: @victoriah I edited where to find the other guy if you follow the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you join the legion you'll do a lot of quests paired with Hadvar (the legionnaire which helps you if you go with him at the beginning). About the rebel guy (not Ulfric) don't know if you'll quest together.